# Pick a slice from R array according to coordinates

Tags: r

I have two vectors `x` and `y` of coordinates and a 3D array `A` in R. I want to produce a matrix, where the i'th row is `A[x[i], , y[i]]`.

If `A` was 2D, I believe I could use `A[cbind(x,y)]`. For the 3D array, I think the following works, but it's kind of slow:

`sapply(1:length(x), function(i) A[x[i],,y[i]])`.

Is there a faster way to do this, e.g. by somehow using `cbind`?

**Edit:**

For instance, consider the following

```
A = array(1:12, c(2,2,3))
x = c(1,2,1)
y = c(1,2,3)

> A
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8

, , 3

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    9   11
[2,]   10   12
```

I would like to get the following output, but with a faster code:

```
> t(sapply(1:length(x), function(i) A[x[i],,y[i]]))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    6    8
[3,]    9   11
```

Comment: Thanks! I added an example with a working code using sapply. I was hoping to find a faster code for doing the same.

Comment: `do.call('rbind', Map(function(a, b)A[a, ,b ], x, y))` may be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
indices <- cbind(
  rep(x, each = dim(A)[2]),
  rep(seq_len(dim(A)[2]), times = length(x)),
  rep(y, each = dim(A)[2])
)

identical(
  array(A[indices], dim = c(dim(A)[2], length(x))),
  sapply(1:length(x), function(i) A[x[i],,y[i]])
)
#> [1] TRUE
```

---

Data:

```
A <- array(1:30, dim = c(2, 3, 5))
n <- 7
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(dim(A)[1], n, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(dim(A)[3], n, replace = TRUE)
```

---

Performance: not necessarily better, depends on use case, see plot for insights

```
set.seed(42)

create_data <- function(array_size, coordinates_size) {
  list(
    A = array(1:array_size^3, dim = rep(array_size, 3)),
    x = sample(array_size, coordinates_size, replace = TRUE),
    y = sample(array_size, coordinates_size, replace = TRUE)
  )
}

results <- bench::press(
  array_size = c(10, 100, 1e3),
  coordinates_size = c(100, 1e3, 10e3),
  {
    dat <- create_data(array_size, coordinates_size)
    A <- dat[["A"]] ; x <- dat[["x"]] ; y <- dat[["y"]]
    bench::mark(
      sapply = {
        sapply(1:length(x), function(i) A[x[i],,y[i]])
      },
      cbind = {
        indices <- cbind(
          rep(x, each = dim(A)[2]),
          rep(seq_len(dim(A)[2]), times = length(x)),
          rep(y, each = dim(A)[2])
        )
        array(A[indices], dim = c(dim(A)[2], length(x)))
      }
    )
  }
)

ggplot2::autoplot(results)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works beautifully! I iterate over A (which is matrix of parameters to be estimated), but I only need to do the indices once. This is much faster than sapply; my matrix A is small (5x3x42), but the length of x and y are large (over 100,000).